# Starting research for building my own router

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

I hope this is going to the right stackexchange group. If this is somehow not the right place, please suggest the right one. I'm trying to build my own solution because I'm not happy with the one provided by the low end household solutions.

Perhaps the biggest problem I have is that I want to attach multiple physical connections to it.  I have Cat5e wiring for now, but am not sure when/if I'll ever change it to the next better one.  The TP-Link and Linksys routers I have now only take 4, but I'd like to be able to have say 12.  I understand a switch usually has a more, but I don't understand how that would work with respect to my router.  Would I plug the devices into the switch, then plug the switch into the router?  Could I simply replace the router with the switch (I think I can't, but I don't know).

Could I get many physical connections by getting a cheap used computer off Craigslist, installing a Linux for routers distro and adding multiple NIC cards?  Is there such a thing as a NIC that has say 12 plugs?

I hope the question does not irritate the reader.  Sometimes the most stupid questions are the hardest to find an answer to.

Secondly, I'd like not use the AT&T U-Verse router that comes with the service.  They claim that you cannot not use the router, but I tend to take a can do (if eventually) attitude.  I don't mind using their modem, but want the control over my internal network, and not have to use a bridge mode.  I'd like it to look like only one device got plugged into the service.

Third, I'm concerned about routers that are a bit *too* consumer friendly.  I'd like to avoid a router that is somehow manageable remotely by the company's service.  I didn't want to go to say linksys.com/myrouter, sign in with personal info  and have it send commands back to the router.  I really want to control my own network, even if that means I have to spend a little more time and learn a little bit more.  I've built my own desktop computers, so I don't mind getting my hands a little bit electronically dirtied.

Thanks,
WM

-

Comment: This question is not within scope here at Super User.

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your own question: Just buy a larger switch and have it linked to the router. No you cant replace the router with a switch. A switch switches between devices on a network and a router routes between different networks.

Answer (score 0):

> The TP-Link and Linksys routers I have now only take 4, but I'd like to be able to have say 12. I understand a switch usually has a more, but I don't understand how that would work with respect to my router. Would I plug the devices into the switch, then plug the switch into the router?

Yes. Imagine that your router has just one "LAN" port on the inside, but connects it to a built-in switch, and it's actually that built-in switch that gives you 4 LAN ports. So you're just chaining a 2nd switch from the built-in switch.

(That's how it actually works. From an IP router's perspective, the entire LAN corresponds to a single interface such as `eth0`, and splitting it up into multiple devices is the Ethernet layer's business.)

> Could I simply replace the router with the switch (I think I can't, but I don't know).

If you're looking for cheap, then no. The router's primary job is to deal with IP addresses (routing and NAT) – a pure Ethernet switch won't do that, nor will it provide the additional functions that the router does, such as issuing addresses via DHCP.

(You could use a Linux or BSD system *as* a router, but you cannot get rid of it entirely – especially considering your requirement of "no bridge mode, look like only one device got plugged into the service". Switches *literally are* bridges.)

But there do exist so-called "L3 switches" which have 20–50 ports but still have full routing functionality built in. (I am not sure whether they typically also have DHCP and NAT, though.)

> Is there such a thing as a NIC that has say 12 plugs?

No; at most they have two or four (and that's usually expensive server-grade NICs). You'd normally achieve this by using an external switch.

---

The rest of your questions are out of scope for this site.